# Why does my sort print out multiple lists?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I tried doing this bubble sort, and when I run it, it prints out the original, and 2 unsorted "sorted" lists, then finally the actual sorted list. How can I get rid of the extra "sorts'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 9

int main(void)
{
    int ray[SIZE]= {8,1,5,8,1,2,4,5,9};
    int i, temp, swapped;

    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        ray[i] ;
    }
    printf("Red ID\n", ray[i]);
    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf(" %d\n", ray[i]);
    }
    while(1){
        swapped = 0; // when swapped = 1, loop repeats, when 0, it ends
        for( i=0; i<SIZE-1; i++){ //the -1 ends it at the second to last digit in the array
            if( ray[i] > ray[i + 1]){
                temp = ray[i];
                ray[i] = ray[i + 1]; // this whole block does the swapping
                ray[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped=1;
            }
        }
        if(swapped==0){
            break;
        }
        printf("\n Sorted Red ID\n");
        for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            printf(" %d\n", ray[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to do with the statement `ray[i] ;`?

Comment: And you do print *in the loop*, maybe you should do that *outside* the loop?

Comment: this does nothing: for( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        ray[i] ;
    }  and should have been flagged by the compiler due to the line: ray[i] ;

Comment: this line: printf("Red ID\n", ray[i]); will always print one past the end of the array.

Comment: this code:        printf("\n Sorted Red ID\n");
        for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            printf(" %d\n", ray[i]);
        } is printing the array on every pass through the while() loop.  It needs to be after the end of the while() loop closing brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print` statement is inside of the `while` loop, so you are printing on each iteration. You need to move the `print` statement outside of the `while` loop, so that it prints once sorting is complete.

```
while(1){
    swapped = 0; // when swapped = 1, loop repeats, when 0, it ends
    for( i=0; i<SIZE-1; i++){ //the -1 ends it at the second to last digit in the array
        if( ray[i] > ray[i + 1]){
            temp = ray[i];
            ray[i] = ray[i + 1]; // this whole block does the swapping
            ray[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped=1;
        }
    }
    if(swapped==0){
        break;
    }
}

printf("\n Sorted Red ID\n");
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
    printf(" %d\n", ray[i]);
}
```